# External SpringBoot properties file on Docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I'm currently trying to automatically externalize my application.yml file from my Spring Boot app's default location `/src/main/resouces/application.yml`. I know currently Spring Cloud Server is a good or prefered way to do so, but that may not be an option for my case at this time.

I'm currently trying to extract the `.yml` file from it's `.jar` and then copy it to my desired folder.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to get it at all! At some point I try to run `RUN ls -lrt /tmp/config` and even though I get a success message from COPY command, it's always empty.

This is my curreny setup:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

VOLUME ["/tmp", "/tmp/config", "/tmp/logs"]

ADD /target/*.jar app.jar

RUN apk add --update unzip && unzip app.jar "*application.yml" && ls -lrt

RUN ls -lrt /BOOT-INF/classes

RUN cp /BOOT-INF/classes/application.yml tmp/config

RUN ls -lrt tmp/config 
# ----> Total 0

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar", "--spring.config.location=file:/tmp/config/application.yml"]
```

And in my docker-compose.yml I have a mapping for all three VOLUMES I'm defining above.

Do you guys have any idea on how to solve this issue without making the user drop the .yml file in the directory at first deploy?

Best regards,
Enrico Bergamo

Comment: Why not use environment variables with compose?

Comment: Or why not just leave the config in the jar file?

Comment: I'm afraid of using env vars with compose because it might start getting to big to maintain. On the other hand, I agree with your suggestion of leaving it in the jar and just editting it as we need and repack it. Unfortunately it seems Operations people in this project don't want to deal with possible updates in this manner and started a fuss already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have just decided keeping it simple and have a volume mounted just for an additional application.yml file. Before running the container, I'm creating the directory and placing my new .yml file in this dir and it did the trick :)

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

VOLUME ["/tmp", "/tmp/config", "/tmp/logs"]

ADD /target/*.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar", "--spring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,file:/tmp/config/application.yml"]
```

Comment: Thanks, should be ```"-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,file:/tmp/config/application.yml"]``` not --